# Interdisciplinary Questions Law and Economics

Tags: discussion, site-scope, acceptable-questions, asking-questions, stackexchange

https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/legal-theory-and-deference-of-a-corporate-law-question-de-lege-ferenda-to-https/866#866

Should I ask https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/43507/limited-liability-and-moral-hazard here? I was defered to money but I think Economics deal with Moral Hazard. While I do not think the capacity to answer the question lies in Economics.

Law as a discipline is inherently interdisciplinary.

Economics, Sociology, Politics, Philosophy, Language; Law it is a mix of all of them.

My question is de lege ferenda. I want an answer on why should the law stay as it is as opposed to a suggestion I made. What would be the disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, I find that the question is long and kind of rambling. If you can make it clearer and succinct, link to the necessary legal phrases and explain on what you mean by "should", e.g. what is your exact goal you might get an answer here.

Comment: Since it is the economics stack exchange and the question is interdisciplinary I would rather ask about positive economics here as opposed to normative economics and let normative part to law. Are you happy seeing a draft of the question? I am not going to post the one I posted in law. Since that one is normative. I am going to happen what happens in such a case.

Comment: Having read the comment I don't know what your question will be. Go ahead and post it, worst case scenario it gets closed. Please try to be very clear in your question.

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/30504/moral-hazard-bubbles-and-economies-of-scale-in-limited-companies-and-organizat